# Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 server does not run on browser

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, vps, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to linux. I have set up my VPS with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit. I have successfully installed Tomcat and successfully started it with `/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/bin/catalina.sh run`.

But when I try to access the default tomcat page with [MyServerIP]:8080, It is unable to connect. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I did a restart and this is all I have in the log.

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 739 ms
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/ROOT
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/docs
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-     7.0.34/webapps/examples
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/host- manager
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/manager
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 02, 2013 8:59:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 870 ms
```

Looks like it never connects

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong, otherwise it would work.  :) But please tell us about the error you got, any logfile entries you might see and anything else that could help.

Comment: `@Shazinltc:` I think its your firewall. Stop the firewall on the ubuntu machine and try again. Or provide some more details along with what error on webpage you are getting.

Comment: This might not be related to your problem, but I think it is better to start tomcat using `/etc/init.d/tomcat7 start` or `service tomcat7 start`.

Comment: @SvenW: Nothing other than 'could not connect to the page'. Is there any other logs that I can check apart from the Tomcat logs?

Comment: @PratapSingh: I have tried by disabling the firewall, but still doesn't work. (I guess sudo ufw disable is the right command)

Comment: @Khaled: Isn't that for automatic start up?

Comment: When tomcat is started, what's the output of wget http://127.0.0.1:80:80 and netstat -ntlp? Your problem can have at least 2 causes : Either tomcat did not start correctly or <yourip>:8080 is filtered by a firewall <- my guess is 2nd option

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU:Yes it is a firewall problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks PratapSingh and Eric DANNIELOU. You guys were right. It was a firewall problem.
Port 8080 was blocked. Added this line : `-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`. Now its working fine.  Thank you again.